# Вывод данных из одного компонента в других Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5

Проблема в следующем. Есть родительский компонент. В нем пять дочерних. Это все одна страница с карточками. Каждая карточка — компонент. В одной карточке я заливаю на сервер csv-файл и сервер сразу же отдает мне json, который мне нужно вывести в остальных карточках (в виде таблиц, графиков) без дополнительных get-запросов. По сути нажал на кнопку отправить, файл ушел и через какое-то время прорисовался во всех компонентах. Get и post-запросы делаю через сервис. Вот только не пойму, как через сервис передать данные, которые пришли в один из компонентов.

Comment: точно так же: сохраняешь в сервисе данные, и в компонентах их читаешь

Answer (score 0):

В методе сервиса, в котором приходит ответ от сервера с json, нужно эмитить ивент с содержимым ответа.

Во всех дочерних компонентах (если это разные компоненты) нужно подписаться на этот ивент - таким образом при получении данных от сервера, все заинтересованные компоненты получат одинаковый результат. Подробности см. здесь https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter